# Save pdf as a byte array using JSReport

Tags: asp.net, database, pdf, actionresult, jsreport

I generate a pdf using JSReport from a view. 
Because my client want to save this generated pdf as a byte[], I'm looking for a solution: 
this is the code I use:

```
[EnableJsReport(Recipe = "phantom-pdf")]
    public ActionResult Result()
    {
        ...
        return View();
    }
```

Any solutions?

Comment: This basically returns byte[] already. The client just needs to read stream of bytes. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JanBlaha
Can you tell me how I can save this byte[] as a variable?
It would help me a lot further

Comment: It depends on the client. It is browser, server language.. ? And what you want to do with byte[]...

Comment: @JanBlaha, the client is a browser. The goal is to save the byte[] into a database, so it can be distributed at a later on.